# Oracle: complex constraint involving other records

Tags: oracle, constraints

Is there any way to make oracle checks other records of a table by a constraint?

Let's take an example:

I've got a table called `ENI_TRASC_VOCI_PWR_FATT` and I want that every record having `tvp_regione` not null has a similar record having `tvp_regione` = null.

For similar record I need to check it has the same value on the `TVP_CODICE_ASSOGGETAMEN` colum.

Comment: So you have pairs of records?  One null, one not null?

Comment: Due to Oracle's limitations on CHECK constraints I think you're going to have to use a trigger (perhaps BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ENI_TRAC_VOCI_PWR_FATT) to perform this validation.

Answer (score 3):

The only method I can think of is to use a fast commit on refresh materialised view, defined with a query something like:

```
select
  tvp_codice_assoggetamen,
  count(*)           rows_per_tca,
  count(tvp_regione) tvp_regione_per_tca
from
  eni_trasc_voci_pwr_fatt
group by
  tvp_codice_assoggetamen
/
```

Place regular check constraints on the MV table, such that tvp_regione_per_tca = 1 if rows_per_tca = 2 (your requirement is not quite clear to me).

That is generally the only safe way of implementing such a multi-row constraint in Oracle, short of locking the table for changes before modifying it and using code to check.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm) :

> Conditions of check constraints cannot contain the following
>   constructs:
>       **Subqueries and scalar subquery expressions**

So You'll probably have to use a trigger instead:

```
create or replace trigger trg
before insert or update on ENI_TRASC_VOCI_PWR_FATT
for each row

begin
   -- do whatever queries you need - I didn't understand what you want
   if <some condition> then
     raise_application_error(-20000,'no good');
   end if;
end;
```

But be carefull ! a trigger is not like a constraint - think what will happen if two users update the table and so on ....

Comment: The trigger won't work, because the OP wants to enforce a constraint across records, which will hurl mutating table exceptions.

Comment: Thanks @APC for the comment, I'm not sure what OP wants... The way I understand it is that you shouldn't allow inserting a record with a value in `tvp_regione` unless there is another recored with null in that field. If so then a trigger can work (though not recomended)

Comment: Yes. I want to act as A.B.Cade says. It is possible? How can I formulate the trigger?

Comment: it is possible but not recomended: lets assume I inserted a row with a "not null value", before I commit, you also insert such a record, the trigger will alow this because it doesn't see my insert in your insert (since I havn't commited yet), then I commit and then you commit, this will probably pass and break your table integrity. Use @David Aldrige answer.